# Calculate $A$ from $ABA$=$C$ where $B$ and $C$ is known

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

as the title says, I look for a way to calculate the 2x2 matrix $A$ if the 2x2 matrices $B$ and $C$ are known with the equation
$A$$B$$A$=$C$

Background: I am at my master thesis in electrical engineering and I have to cancel the influence of connectors to a measurement. The influence of the connector is described by a 2x2 matrix(S-parameter) $A$, which I don't know. I know however the S-Parameter of the DUT $B$ and the resulting S-Parameters $C$ by measurement.

Comment: If it is a $2\times2$ matrix can't you just solve the equations?

Comment: This problem is not solvable in general, for example if $B$ is the zero matrix and $C$ is not.  Could you include the form for $B$ and $C$?  Assuming it is solvable you are going to need those forms

Comment: If $A$ solves the problem, so does $-A$. So there is no unique solution in general.

Comment: $B$ and $C$ are not zero. The equation should be solvable for the matrices I plug in as they result from direct measurement of the physical system.

Comment: Even in the very simple case $B=C=I$ this leads to $A^2=I$ with an infinity of solutions. For instance $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & a \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ and chosing $a=0$ does not give $A=I$ which can be expected in this situation. So how are you supposed to sort out the possible solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excluding pathological cases for $\bf A$ and $\bf B$, then you can follow
these steps
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\bf A}\;{\bf B}\;{\bf A} = {\bf C}  \cr 
  & {\bf A}\;{\bf B}\;{\bf A}\;{\bf B} = \left( {{\bf A}\;{\bf B}} \right)^{\,{\bf 2}} \; = {\bf C}\;{\bf B}  \cr 
  & {\bf A}\;{\bf B}\; = \left( {{\bf C}\;{\bf B}} \right)^{\,1/{\bf 2}}   \cr 
  & {\bf A} = \left( {{\bf C}\;{\bf B}} \right)^{\,1/{\bf 2}} \;{\bf B}^{\, - \,1} \; \cr} 
$$

Concerning the square root, pay attention to fact that there might be more than one (or none real):
have a look to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix).

One point that might help is to diagonalize, or put in Jordan form, the matrix $\bf{CB}$.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution seems to work for my application.
To mention it: The S-parameters are already complex because they convey a phase information. I wrote a python script that successfully calculated the values for me and they seem to fit.

Comment: @user3219624:  Good, glad that it helped. You might then consider to mark the answer as accepted.